# How do I make this line of code into a defined function to make my code more clean?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
y_total = sum(i for i in y_input)
x_total = sum(i for i in x_input)
z_total = sum(i for i in z_input)
q_total = sum(i for i in q_input)
```

Above me I have a fraction of the lines of code in my Python IDLE and from my point of view, this looks very REPETITIVE, I don't want to keep having to type `sum(i for i in _____)` for every sum I want to take. I'm still a beginner at this Python stuff, but I did do some external research before this. So far I managed to do something like this but it's not much since I am not sure how to "generalize" the code to make it reusable.

```
def sum():
```

Comment: What is `y_input`? A list?

Comment: those lines of code take the sum of inputs for y, where y_input is just a name I used to store the users inputs when prompted for values of y

Comment: There's an inbuilt `sum` which does what you want already. Additionally, defining your own function `def sum():` might cause unexpected behavior elsewhere when people use the code.

Answer (score 1):

As long as `y_input` &co. are iterable, you do not need that generator expression. Use:

```
y_total = sum(y_input)
x_total = sum(x_input)
z_total = sum(z_input)
q_total = sum(q_input)
```

Comment: And if they're not iterable, you can't use the genexp in the first place.

Comment: How do I make def function that does this so I can call it?

Comment: @user3720526: You don't need to write your own function. The built-in `sum` already does exactly what you want.

Comment: @user3720526: If you want to apply `sum` to all 4 lists in one line, you could do `x_total, y_total, z_total, q_total = map(sum, [x_input, y_input, z_input, q_input])`.

Comment: As @user2357112 said, `sum` is already there (a builtin, really). Just use that, no need to write a new function.

Comment: Just for the heck of it, what if I wanted to just scrap the built in sum function and write out the sum function manually and then save it as a module? I'm not sure if I even make sense here.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Since cPython is open source, you can read the code: [here is the `sum()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1e30ecbfe181/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2296). TL;DR the code is just an optimized version of a `for` loop which adds all the elements, like: `result = 0; for x in data: result += x`

Comment: @user3720526 Don't worry if the code for `sum` from the link is confusing. It's written in C, not Python, so is more complicated than might be expected.